# Autoplay embedded Youtube video's

Tags: youtube, autoplay

I've been trying to let an embedded youtube video play automatically.

My link looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/IJNR2EpS0jw?rel=o&?autoplay=1&mute=1
SO i've added the parameters **?rel=0, ?autoplay=1 ,mute=1**

the Posts I've followed are :
[Embedded YouTube iframes No Longer Autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189735/embedded-youtube-iframes-no-longer-autoplay)
[Autoplay embedded a YouTube Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843592/autoplay-embedded-a-youtube-video)

Is this actually possible due to the private changes of Autoplay and muted autoplay?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to autoplay muted YouTube video, but the problem in your embed link is the `?`(question mark you have used before `autoplay`, which is not letting it to autoplay).
Use `https://www.youtube.com/embed/IJNR2EpS0jw?rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=1`, and I hope this will work.